# Python 3 and Twitch API?

Tags: python, twitch

Is there any possible way to use the Twitch.tv API with Python 3? It looks to be prepared for another language but I've been spending a lot of time learning Python.

Comment: [This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitch/0.1.4) imported into python 3.4 for me

Answer (score 1):

Install it with `pip3 install python-twitch` and read the formal documentation [here](http://ingwinlu.github.io/python-twitch).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can import **requests** which is a great module to deal with api's. Here is more documentation on it.

> import requests
>
> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>
> r.status_code
>
> r.headers['content-type']
>
> r.encoding
>
> r.json()

source: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/